# Apache server redirection issue with bootstrap template

Tags: php, .htaccess, apache2, web-deployment, apache2.4

I downloaded web version of this bootstrap template:

https://w3layouts.com/spike-shoes-flat-ecommerce-responsive-web-template/

I have VPS with LAMP stack installed. I tried to deploy this template into the

**/var/www/html/Store** directory

That directory contains index.php and .htaccess file. The index.php contains this information:

```
<?php 
/*
 * A Design by W3layouts
Author: W3layouts
Author URL: http://w3layouts.com
License: Creative Commons Attribution 3.0 Unported
License URL: http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by/3.0/
 *
 */
include "app/config.php";
include "app/detect.php";

if ($page_name=='') {
    include $browser_t.'/index.html';
    }
elseif ($page_name=='index.html') {
    include $browser_t.'/index.html';
    }
elseif ($page_name=='login.html') {
    include $browser_t.'/login.html';
    }
elseif ($page_name=='details.html') {
    include $browser_t.'/details.html';
    }
elseif ($page_name=='register.html') {
    include $browser_t.'/register.html';
    }
elseif ($page_name=='products.html') {
    include $browser_t.'/products.html';
    }
elseif ($page_name=='contact.html') {
    include $browser_t.'/contact.html';
    }
elseif ($page_name=='contact-post.html') {
    include 'app/contact.php';
    }
else
    {
        include $browser_t.'/404.html';
    }

?>
```

and .htaccess this information:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
#RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

However, there is a problem with link redirection inside the bootstrap template. For example when i click the login button, the apache server says that:

```
Not Found

The requested URL /Store/login.html was not found on this server.
Apache/2.4.7 (Ubuntu) Server at www.domain.fi Port 80
```

I read from this site https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-use-the-htaccess-file, that:

> Each time a page loads, the server scans its directory, and any above it until it reaches the highest directory or an .htaccess file. This process will occur as long as the AllowOverride allows the use of .htaccess files, whether or not the file the .htaccess files actually exists.

So i went and configured /etc/apache2/apache2.conf from this:

```
<Directory /var/www/>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride None
        Require all granted
</Directory>
```

to this:

```
<Directory /var/www/>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted
</Directory>
```

However, the Apache server still gives the same error message. What could be wrong?

Comment: Have you restarted Apache?

Comment: Yes i forgot to add that. I have restarted apache server with command: sudo service apache2 restart

Comment: I solved the problem by turning mod_rewrite on with command: sudo a2enmod rewrite. Now the redirection works correctly. Anyone who is having the same problem can check this link https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-mod_rewrite